# Zend Framework compability with Lucene 8.4.1

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am using Lucene 3.5.0 for index creation. Zend-Framework-1.8.2 with PHP-7.1.12 is being used to search index.

I have upgraded Lucene from 3.5.0 to 8.4.1. The indexes are now created with Lucene 8.4.1. But searching index gives error. I believe I need to upgrade Zend-Framework and PHP.

So, could anyone please provide the pointers on which Zend-Framework and PHP version is compatible to use with Lucene 8.4.1 indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Well ... bad news for you.

The Zend Search component concerning Lucene is not maintained since years and has been archived a long time ago. Even on Packagist the package is marked as *This package is abandoned and no longer maintained. No replacement package was suggested.*

Same goes for Zend Framework. Even Zend Framework 3 is not maintained anymore. The follow up is the [Laminas Framework](https://www.getlaminas.org).

My suggestion would be that you switch to Laminas, the successor to Zend Framework. Most components of the Laminas Framework are already PHP 8.1 compatible. Say goodbye to the ZendSearch component. This component is not developed further and will prevent you from using current PHP versions in the future. PHP 7.3 has reached an end of life already. PHP 7.4 is in a security fixes only state since december 2021 and will reach an end of life by end of this year. Zend Framework and ZendSearch will not work for the foreseeable future, if they should work now.

Just use one of the following alternatives:

- [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co)
- [Pucene](https://github.com/pucene)
- [Solr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php)
- [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com)